# Load an SVF in viewer from OSS bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I translated an Inventor model to SVF using CreateSVFPlugin. I got a zip, which when extracted has  the folder structure as attached in the image.
Now how do I load this in the viewer. I have the zip I got as output from CreateSVFPlugin in OSSbucket. [SVFOutputFolderStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEp1j.png)

I'm using the below code

```
var options = {
            env: 'Local',
            getAccessToken: getForgeToken
        };


        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async () => {
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'] });
            viewer.start("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/<>/objects/test.svf", options);

            resolve()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewer needs the *.svf file (and all the files it references) to be individually accessible via URLs. I'm not sure how exactly your server app is structured but one option would be to extract the zip file from the OSS bucket into a subfolder somewhere on your server, and have your server application serve individual files from that subfolder. Then you can point the viewer to the actual *.svf file, for example like so:

```js
viewer.loadModel('http://localhost:8080/some-subfolder/foo/bar.svf');
```